# cvxopt for Markowitz Portfolio Optimization - finding point of optimal Sharpe Ratio

Tags: portfolio, cvxopt

I've been trying for 3 days to understand how to use cvxopt module in python to calculate the efficient frontier. A code snippet that I found at: https://github.com/markharley/Markowitz/blob/master/markowitz.py

is probably the best way to illustrate my problem, and I have included in entirety at the bottom of this post.

Using the equations found on the wikipedia page for Modern Portoflio Theory:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory#Efficient_frontier_with_no_risk-free_asset

[image]

I understand why the first use of solvers.qp uses:

```
solvers.qp(S, -q*pbar, G, h, A, b)['x']
```

where q is a risk tolerance factor.
The code then goes on to calculate the point of optimal Sharpe Ratio using polyfit, which I also understand, but where I am lost is why the code now is:

```
# Calculate the optimal portfolio
wt = solvers.qp(opt.matrix(x1 * S), -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x']
```

where x1 is the return at the point of optimal Sharpe Ratio. I am lost as to why all of a sudden we can multiply S (covariance matrix) by x1 and also get rid of q in the -pbar term.

Could anyone shed some light on this please? Apologies if I am not explaining this properly, any request for clarification would probably help me make my question clearer as well.

Thanks!

```
def optimal_portfolio(returns):
n = len(returns)
returns = np.asmatrix(returns)

N = 100
qs = [10**(-5.0 * t/N + 1.0) for t in range(N)]

# Convert to cvxopt matrices
S = opt.matrix(np.cov(returns))

# np.mean computes vector of means along
# as mean of each row
pbar = opt.matrix(np.mean(returns, axis=1))

# Create constraint matrices
# -- documentation at http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-programming
G = -opt.matrix(np.eye(n)) # negative nxn id
h = opt.matrix(0.0, (n, 1)) # n x 1 zero vector
A = opt.matrix(1.0, (1, n)) # 1 x n 1-vector
b = opt.matrix(1.0) # [1.0]

## Calculate efficient frontier weights using quadratic programming
## https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming
# Minimizes (1/2) w^T * S * w - q pbar^T * w for weights w
# subject to the constrains:
# G * w <= h (component-wise) -- positive weights
# and A*w = b -- Sum of weights == 1
# where S is the covariance matrix,
# pbar are the mean returns,
# q is a measure of risk tolerance
portfolios = [solvers.qp(S, -q*pbar, G, h, A, b)['x'] for q in qs]

## Could replace above with Lagrange multiplier (or convex hull)

# Calculate risks and mean returns for frontier
returns = [blas.dot(pbar, x) for x in portfolios]
risks = [np.sqrt(blas.dot(x, S * x)) for x in portfolios]

# Calculate quadratic for the frontier curve
m1 = np.polyfit(returns, risks, 2)
x1 = np.sqrt(m1[2] / m1[0])

# Calculate the optimal portfolio
wt = solvers.qp(opt.matrix(x1 * S), -pbar, G, h, A, b)['x']

return np.asarray(wt), returns, risks
```

Comment: Hi @Wei, could you show why x1 is the return at the optimal Sharpe-Ratio portfolio?

Comment: @Wei, did you arrive at a resolution to this problem?

Comment: Very sorry, I never reached resolution and I just noticed there were 2 follow up questions here.